# Displaying a Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a new security assessment webpage in which I am using HTML and Java Script. For some reason, the code is not working properly. The way the page supposed to work is by having the user answer Yes or No questions, and when the user is done they click submit. Then the page would display the number of questions answered yes, and a message if the user passed or failed the assessment. But when I click submit, I only see the result, not the message.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

```js
function sumInputs() {
  var text;
  var score = document.getElementById("total").value;

  if (score < 60) {
    text = "You have failed the Assessment";
  } else(score > 60) {
    text = "You have passed the Assessment";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function calcscore() {
  var score = 0;
  $(".calc:checked").each(function() {
    score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}

$().ready(function() {
  $(".calc").change(function() {
    calcscore()

  });
});

window.sumInputs = function() {
  var inputs = $('.calc:checked'),
    result = document.getElementById('total'),
    sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }

  $('#total').val(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges?
        <form>
          Yes
          <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" /> No
          <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge? Yes
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" /> No
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified on the Badge? Yes
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" /> No
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />

  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="sumInputs()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are there two HTML documents at Question?

Comment: I would start fixing the syntax errors, have a look at your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works. Also check your variable type

```js
function calcscore() {
     var score = 0;
     $(".calc:checked").each(function() {
         score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
     });
     $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
 }
 
 
 $().ready(function() {
     $(".calc").change(function() {
         calcscore()
     });
 });



 
 function sumInputs() {
     var inputs = $('.calc:checked'),
         result = document.getElementById('total'),
         sum = 0;

     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
         sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
     }

     $('#total').val(sum);

     var text, score = document.getElementById("total").value;

     if (score < 60) {
         text = "You have failed the Assessment";
     } else if(score > 60) {
         text = "You have passed the Assessment";
     }

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
  <body>

  <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>
   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges? 

<form>
Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />

</form> 


 </td>

   
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge? 


<form>
Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />

</form> 


</td>
    
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified
on the Badge?

<form>
 Yes
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" />
No
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />

</form> 

</td>
      
  </tr>
 
 
</table>

Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>



<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="sumInputs()">

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please described what exactly you changed.

Comment: @winDither Thanks for your help. Now I can see the message, but not the result of the assessment.

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions named `sumInputs`; the second one (which filled the 'score' field) was overwriting the first one (which was supposed to output the message.)

Additionally the scoring was trying to be based on percentages, but never calculated a percentage, just a count of correct questions.

(There were also a couple of syntax errors here and there.)

Correcting all those by merging the two sumInputs functions results in:

```js
function calcscore() {
  var score = 0;
  $(".calc:checked").each(function() {
    score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $("input[name=sum]").val(score)
}

$().ready(function() {
  $(".calc").change(function() {
    calcscore()
  });
});

window.sumInputs = function() {
  var inputs = $('.calc:checked'),
    result = document.getElementById('total'),
    sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
  }

  $('#total').val(sum);
  
  var score = sum / 3 * 100; // calculate percentage

  if (score < 60) {
    text = "You have failed the Assessment";
  } else { // no need for else if (score > 60)... which would have failed if the score was exactly 60
    text = "You have passed the Assessment";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges?
        <form>
          Yes
          <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" /> No
          <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge? Yes
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" /> No
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified on the Badge? Yes
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" /> No
        <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />

  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="sumInputs()">
</body>

</html>
```

Incidentally, the `calcscore()` function is unnecessary -- it updates the displayed score while the user takes the quiz, but the sumInputs function used at the end of the quiz doesn't depend on it.  If you don't want to give the user immediate feedback on whether each question was correct or not, you can remove that function (and move `$("input[name=sum]").val(score)` into `sumInputs()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added some already done modifications, and changed the plain javascript to jquery.

```js
$('.calc').change(function() {
    calcscore();            
});

$('#submitted').click(function() {

    sumInputs();
    result();

});

function sumInputs() {

    var inputs = $('.calc:checked'), 
        result = $('#total').val(), 
        sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }

    $('#total').val(sum);

}

function result() {

    var text;
    var score = (( $('#total').val() ) / 3 ) * 100;
    var score = score.toFixed(2);            

    if (score < 60) {
        text = "Total " + score + ": You have failed the Assessment";
    }
    else {            
        text = "Total " + score + ": You have passed the Assessment";
    }

    $('#demo').text(text);
}

function calcscore() {

    var score = 0;

    $('.calc:checked').each(function () {                
        score += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });

    $('#total').val(score);

}
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h1>Security Assessment </h1>

    <form>        
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>PERSONNEL SECURITY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1. Does your staff wear ID badges?
                Yes <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" /> 
                No <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio1" value="0" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. Is a current picture part of the ID badge? 
                Yes <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="1" /> 
                No <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio2" value="0" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. Are authorized access levels and type (employee, contractor, visitor) identified on the Badge? 
                Yes <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="1" /> 
                No <input class="calc" type="radio" name="radio3" value="0" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />
    <input id="submitted" type="Submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    
</body>
</html>
```